# how to implement keep alive in hazelcast cluster of verticles

Tags: cluster-computing, microservices, hazelcast, vert.x, vertx-verticle

i have some verticles that belong to the same cluster and they send a hello message over the event bus -the message is basically the sending verticle's name- to a receiver verticle which stores the message in a map.

i want to implement a keep alive method so if i kill one of the senders the message it sent to the receiver is deleted from the receiver's map.

i looked at the hazelcast website but i didn't find an easy way to implement that feature.

the expected result is to have the sender's record deleted from the receiver's map when the sender's verticle is stopped/killed.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [MembershipListener](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#listening-for-member-events) and listen to the membership changes. This way you can remove the previously added messages of a member when it leaves the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple ways to achieve this and one is using Hazelcast [ILock's](https://docs.hazelcast.org//docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#lock)  would be an easier approach, each member can take a lock (maybe with a verticle name), and when a member leaves the cluster, all the locks acquired by that dead member will be auto-removed so your application can check if it's locked or not anytime.